# check if variable name is the same a string inside an array

Tags: javascript

I have several arrays that I `json_encode` form php and two variables that I get from an inputs, lets say :

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
let b = [1,2,3,4,5];
let c = [1,2,3,4,5];
let d = [1,2,3,4,5];
let e = [1,2,3,4,5];
let f = [1,2,3,4,5];

let name = document.getElementById("some_element").value
let number = document.getElementById("some_other_element").value
```

I wanna check if the `name` is the same as the array name and then use the array with the `name` for example `a[number]`.

I am not quite sure of how to do this. Any help would be really welcome.

Comment: So `#some_element`'s value might be `c` and `#some_other_element`'s value might be `4` and you'd want `c[4]` which is the number `5`?

Comment: yeah sorry @DM it's like that, and the answer is what enzo wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object:

```js
const arrays = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  c: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  d: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  e: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  f: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
};

const name = "a";
const number = 1;

console.log(arrays[name][number]);
```

Comment: yes thanks mate I didn't think of that thank you very much.